# PHP - XML conversion

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm new to stackoverflow and after some searching didn't find an answer to my question so I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I have to use this web service method that takes three parameters, a string and two xml params.

Below's an example of the code I'm using. The web service method throws an exception, 'Required parameters for method SubmitXml are null.'

So I'm guessing it's not receiving any xml on the 2nd and 3rd params. Can anyone give me a hint on how to correctly use the DOM or any other with PHP here? thank you in advance.

```
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($this-SOAPURL, array('login'=>$this->account,'password'=>$this->password));

    $xmlstr ='<xmlbody>';
    $xmlstr.='<someXML>Some XML text content here!</someXML>';
    $xmlstr.='</xmlbody>';

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($xmlstr);
    $filter = new DOMDocument();

    $filter->loadXML('<_ xmlns=""/>');
    print_r ($soapClient->SubmitXml('userIDString',$dom->saveXML(), $fil->saveXML()));
```

Comment: Does SoapClient even have the method SubmitXml()? :) Why not use an object structure...or at least array to send the request...bottom line that's what SOAP is all about (Simple Object Access Protocol) :) ? http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

Comment: SubmitXml's a method belonging to the web service itself, as returned by the SoapClient::__getFunctions() method... using SoapClient::__soapCall or calling the method directly would actually be the same, right?

Comment: @José Albernaz Senra: Yes, sort of the same as it's a webservice function. Check your syntax however and that you use the right variable names. I suggest you enable error reporting and the highest level of warning `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your script.

Comment: @hakre: Thanks hakre... got error reporting enabled and did get the error thrown by the webservice method. my question is will $dom->saveXML() return a valid XML to be used by the method?

Answer (score 0):

After some struggling I finally got it. It didn't end up being a syntax error or anything. The code I presented in my question was OK except that I wasn't wrapping my XML string in a required node... something like:

```
$xmlstring = "<somenode>" . $xmlstring . "</somenode>";
```

and then send it to the function.

Thank you all for helping in trying to solve this 'mistery' ;)